# How get DateTime.Now with "AM" not "ق.ظ"

Tags: c#, datetime

I try to get DateTime.Now , but what I get is:

> '23/05/2016 03:16:51 ق.ظ'

I want to have

> '23/05/2016 03:16:51 AM'

or something like this

Comment: You can use `DateTime.Now.ToString(string Format)`, and specify what format you want. Check MSDN for applicable formats.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"))`

Comment: Or possibly `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, depending on the context.

Comment: @raidensan That isn't enough. OP ought to specify the culture in this case.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel then, there is a catch here. If I recall correctly the first output is from Persian calendar. If OP wants to just change the AM/PM specifier of Persian culture, he can change these from System Regional settings or, by specifying CultureInfo of app. I highly suspect that OP use `DateTime.Now` without  giving any format at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you current culture seems to be an arabic one. You can use the [overload of `DateTime.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var enUsCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string result = DateTime.Now.ToString( enUsCulture );
```

an an alternative you could pass the exact format with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`(to avoid that `/` will be replaced with your current culture's date separator):

```
string result = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The `InvariantCulture` avoids that the [`"/" custom format specifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator) will cause `/` to be replaced with your current culture's date separator.

Comment: "To be sure": `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))`

Comment: Not the invariant culture?

Comment: @stuartd: no, it does not use the `AM/PM` designator. But i've used a different approach where `InvariantCulture` would be useful to supress the the [`"/" custom format specifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a specific CultureInfo with your requirements starting from the CurrentCulture

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID);
ci.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator = "AM";
ci.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator = "PM";
ci.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss tt";
string result = DateTime.Now.ToString(ci);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: thank you , it works too, but I had one way to choose

Answer (score 0):

I think CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is the key here

```
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string result = now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This should give you "23 May 2016 02:32 PM", you can further edit the date and time by using other setting in the string format specifier. But keep InvarianCulture and tt in order to recieve AP/PM.

For all possible formats and some examples check these links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format